# boost::hash<double> odd behavior on RHEL 5.4 64bit

Tags: c++, boost, hash, double

I wrote a simple code to understand boost::hash behavior, the source code as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/functional/hash.hpp"

namespace myns {

  size_t get_hash(double v) {
    boost::hash<double> haser;
    return haser(v);
  }
}

int main() {
  double arr[] = {1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0};
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    std::cout << "Hash for " << arr[i] << " is " << myns::get_hash(arr[i]) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Scenario #1: running in release build (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)), the output looks like:

```
Hash for 1 is 140736533409552
Hash for 1 is 4607182418800017408
Hash for 2 is 4607182418800017408
Hash for 1 is 4611686018427387904
Hash for 3 is 4607182418800017408
Hash for 2 is 4613937818241073152
```

Scenario #2: running in debug build (same compiler), the output is:

```
Hash for 1 is 4607182418800017408
Hash for 1 is 4607182418800017408
Hash for 2 is 4611686018427387904
Hash for 1 is 4607182418800017408
Hash for 3 is 4613937818241073152
Hash for 2 is 4611686018427387904
```

Is the behavior of release build normal? in Scene #1, hash of 1, 2, 3 are of the same, and hash of 1 while running for 3 times are different! How could I make it work properly like in debug build? Could anyone please shed me some light? Thanks.

The GCC option line is: g++ -fnon-call-exceptions -O2 -I include/ main.cpp, if I remove fnon-call-exception option, this problem goes.

Comment: I haven't got boost, but I used your code with std::hash (C2011) and it worked correctly.  hasher(1.0) == hasher(2.0) is definitely wrong.  I'm using VC Express 2013 on Win7, 32-bit.

Comment: Put some debugging code in get_hash() to test the return of haser().  Just to confirm that is where the error is.  e.g.  size_t h = haser(v);  std::cerr << "\nhaser(" << v << ") = " << h << '\n'; return h;

Comment: Thanks for answering, Michael. I've also tried CentOS 6.4 64bit GCC 4.4.7, Windows 7 64bit MSVC 2008, both cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion on putting debugging code in get_hash(), the output is kinda the same. I believe it has something to do with the -fnon-call-exceptions option, if I remove it (or the -O2 option), this problem goes.

Comment: What version of boost was this, anyway?

Comment: The boost version is 1.54.0, sorry I miss that.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Following is kinda a final version workaround:

```
  size_t get_hash(double v) {
#if (__GNUC__ && __GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ == 1 && __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ == 2)
  switch(std::fpclassify(v))
  {
  case FP_ZERO:
    return 0;
  case FP_INFINITE:
    return (std::size_t)(v > 0 ? -1 : -2);
  case FP_NAN:
    return -3;
  case FP_NORMAL:
  case FP_SUBNORMAL:
#if defined(__x86_64__)
    return *((size_t*)&v);
#else
    long long ll = *((long long*)&v);
    size_t seed = ll & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    seed ^= (ll>>32) + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
    return seed;
#endif
  default:
    assert(false);
    return 0;
  }
#else
  boost::hash<double> haser;
  return haser(v);
#endif
  }
```

Hope it's useful for who met with the same problem and couldn't update their compiler.

@David Schwartz, it shall not be a bug of boost, this issue can be reproduced with a simpler code:

```
#include <iostream>

size_t hash(size_t x) {
  return x;
}

size_t hash(double d) {
  size_t x = *(size_t*)&d;
  return hash(x);
}

int main() {
  double arr[] = {1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0};
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    std::cout << "Hash for " << arr[i] << " is " << hash(arr[i]) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Check its assembly code (with g++ -S) you'll see following:

```
.LCFI0:
        movq    (%rsp), %rdi
        movsd   %xmm0, (%rsp)
        call    _Z4hashm
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

Here %rdi is messed up. My conclusion is: not to transfer an re-interpreted data of double as a function parameter.

Comment: Note that this workaround strongly relies on [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Reading from another union member than the one last written, is undefined and can (ironically) [be optimized by a conformant compiler](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959). You **should** favour `memcpy` as it's well defined

Comment: Thanks sehe, I've updated the code per your comment.

Comment: Needs a few static asserts on the various assumed sizes of `long long` and `double`. Also, I think it's only defined behaviour if you use `(char*)`, instead of `(void*)`. (Also, in the case of Undefined Behaviour, the compiler can, and should, optimize it all away (and return indeterminate values), since the job of the compiler is to _implement the language specification_ and _generate optimal code_. No code is optimal code :/)

Comment: @EdwardZhang Your "simpler code" probably has the same bug that boost has -- `size_t x = *(size_t*)&d;` is nonsense and relies on UB. (What if `double` and `size_t` have different size and alignment?) Can you replicate the problem in code that doesn't rely on UB?

Answer (score 0):

No, this behaviour is **not** normal.

Your code is fine.

Ergo: it's a bug in the compiler.

It's not reproducible in any recent version of the compiler, so the logical course of action would be to upgrade. (I don't think GCC will accept new bug reports on this old version)

Comment: Thank you, sehe. Actually it comes from a defect I met with in our product, it took me a couple of days to dig out the root cause and generate code to reproduce this issue. We're near the end of product release, so upgrade compiler is not an option now. I kinda figure out a workaround for this and have pasted it in my original post.

Comment: @EdwardZhang Consider posting an answer if it is useful to others. In all other cases, just delete the question :)

Comment: It's more likely, IMO, that it's a bug in boost.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I think not, please check my answer for details.

Comment: @EdwardZhang Your answer replicates it with buggy code, likely code that has the same bug that I suspect boost has.